# Writing raw bytes to a file in Python3 results in unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, byte

So, I have this piece of code:

```
f = open("crash.txt", "w")
junk = ("\xCC" * 1028)
f.write(junk)
f.close()
```

When I run this on Windows(3.5.1), I get a file with repeated "CC"s as hex characters. That is as expected.

However, running this on Linux(Python 3.4.2), I get repeated "c38c"s as hex characters.

I do not understand the output on Linux. Why does this happen and how do I fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by c38c as hex? Do you mean `\xc3\x8c`?

Comment: @Reti43 Yes. When I look at the contents of the file in a hex editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't writing raw bytes.  By default Python 3 uses Unicode strings, and those strings must be encoded to write them to a file.  Also by default, `open()` uses text mode and the encoding used to encode text is `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.  On US Windows, that is `cp1252`, but on Linux, it is usually `utf8`.

`b'\xc3\x8c'` is `'\xcc'` encoded in `utf8`.

`b'\xcc'` is `'\xcc'` encoded in `cp1252`.

Open the file in binary mode and write byte strings instead of Unicode to write "raw" bytes.

```
with open("crash.txt", "wb") as f:
    junk = b"\xCC" * 1028
    f.write(junk)
```

Comment: @Mark Tolonen I am trying to write a byte type variable into a file. any suggestion?